# Changing the position of the red minus button in a UITableViewCell while in Edit Mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

This code worked great inside a UITableViewCell subclass on iOS 5 and 6:

```
if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellEditControl"]) {
        CGRect newFrame = subview.frame;
        //Use your desired x value
        newFrame.origin.x = 280;
        subview.frame = newFrame;    
}
```

While debugging my app on iOS 7 i've found that all the subviews above are called `UITableViewCellContentView` and there is no way knowing where the `UITableViewCellEditControl` subview is.

Is there a better solution for doing the above?

Comment: try recursive check on subViews.

Comment: @santhu Already did that and found that `UITableViewCellEditControl` is inside a subview of a subview. I've posted an answer, Thanks

Comment: I once came across this problem to hack subviews of subviews. But people say if we do this , app might get rejected by apple.

Comment: @santhu Right now I see no other way for doing the above. We'll just have to wait and see if an update of this app will get rejected.

Comment: @Segev Did you pass the review in app store?

Comment: @Segev Thanks for the confirm so that i can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While debugging this I've found that all the subviews in iOS 7 are now called 'UITableViewCellEditControl". I tried logging all the subviews subviews and found that `UITableViewCellEditControl` is now a subview of a subview. This is an ugly temporary solution:

```
for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
    {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellEditControl"]) {
            CGRect newFrame = subview.frame;
            newFrame.origin.x = 280;
            subview.frame = newFrame;
        }
        else
        {
            if(IS_OS_7_OR_LATER)
            {
                for(UIView *subsubview in subview.subviews)
                {
                    if ([NSStringFromClass([subsubview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellEditControl"]) {
                        CGRect newFrame = subsubview.frame;
                        newFrame.origin.x = 280;
                        subsubview.frame = newFrame;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```